# Mysql: Delete duplicate records based on minimum amount

Tags: php, mysql

I need to delete duplicate records based on minimum `amount` for same `order number`. Table has 100k records and structure is like this.
`tmp_id` is `primary key` in this table.

```
------------------------------------
user_id   order_number amount  tmp_id
-------------------------------------
15         12364        25      1
20         454544       75      2
4          12364        100     3
6          45487        45      4
8          454544       330     5
```

I tried like this to `delete` the minimum amount of duplicate records using

```
$qb_duplicate_data_query="select user_id,order_number,amount from tmp_qbappraiser limit 10";

$qb_duplicate_data_sql=mysql_query($qb_duplicate_data_query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qb_duplicate_data_sql)) {
     $amount=$row['amount'];
     $order_no=$row['order_number'];

     $sql="SELECT c1.tmp_id from tmp_qbappraiser c1
inner join (SELECT tmp_id FROM tmp_qbappraiser WHERE order_number='$order_no' ORDER BY amount asc) AS c 
on c.tmp_id=c1.tmp_id GROUP BY c1.order_number having count(order_number)>1";

     $query=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

     $result=mysql_fetch_array($query);

     $db_tmp_id=$result['tmp_id'];

     if($db_tmp_id!='') {
         $delete_sql="delete from tmp_qbappraiser where order_number='$order_no' and tmp_id='$db_tmp_id'";

         $delete_query=mysql_query($delete_sql) or die(mysql_error());
     }

}
```

When I execute this code I get `lock wait timeout exceeded try restarting transaction` error. How to optimize my query or is there any other way to delete the thousands of records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to write multiple queries for deleting duplicate entry, this could be done with one single query.

```
delete t1 from tmp_qbappraiser t1
join tmp_qbappraiser t2
on t1.order_number = t2.order_number
and t1.amount < t2.amount ;
```

The above query will keep the max amount per `order_number` and will delete the rest.

You may need to add some indexes in the table for making it faster

```
alter table tmp_qbappraiser add index ord_amt_idx(order_number,amount);
```

Note: Make sure to take a backup of the table before applying index and running the delete query.

Comment: Thanks.Works like champ !.

Comment: Previously i tried with this query `DELETE n1 FROM tmp_qbappriaser n1, tmp_qbappriaser n2 WHERE n1.amount < n2.amount AND n1.order_number = n2.order_number`. but it takes too much time but not executed.Could you tell me why it takes so much time

Comment: It was perhaps missing the indexes and its always better to use explicit join syntax instead of implicit like you did `FROM tmp_qbappriaser n1, tmp_qbappriaser n2 `